# custom Component register javascript.. getting weird Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, custom-component

i am working on a new template.which contains an api called panel actions. it enables to create action icons on bootstrap panel. i want load thesee panels dynamically..what i meant is that after the complete page loading i want to add new panels with these action.but when i do like that it gives me error

```
     $.components.register("panel", {
  api: function() {
    $(document).on('click.site.panel', '[data-toggle="panel-fullscreen"]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
        $panel = $this.closest('.panel');

      var api = $panel.data('panel-api');
      api.toggleFullscreen();
    });});
```

this how panel api in javascript..and here is panel in html

```
<div class="panel is-collapse">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel With Tool</h3>
              <div class="panel-actions">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle panel-action" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon wb-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu bullet" role="menu">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Another action</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <a class="panel-action icon wb-refresh" data-toggle="panel-refresh" data-load-type="round-circle" data-load-callback="customRefreshCallback" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                <a class="panel-action icon wb-plus" data-toggle="panel-collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                <a class="panel-action icon wb-expand" data-toggle="panel-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                <a class="panel-action icon wb-close" data-toggle="panel-close" aria-hidden="true"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
          </div>
```

when i load these dynamically it gives an error that saying 'Undefined'
eg:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleFullscreen' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

First, `panel-api` isn't defined anywhere in your html on any of your components. Secondly, you're just getting the property, not loading a library, so `toggleFullscreen` wouldn't exist as a call. Looks like you're  missing an intermediate step here.